# Repack app to ipa over SSH

Tags: ios, ssh, cross-platform, itunes, jailbreak

I'm building a backup/restore program for iOS and I've run across a problem. I need to be able to take an app that is installed on a device and repack it into an ipa file, metadata and all (retaining stuff like the iTunes account of the user who bought it, etc.). Furthermore, this needs to be done over SSH, since a lot of these backups will be done using an SSH Ramdisk. Could anyone give some insight on how to do this (cross-platform)? I know that 25pp and vShare can do this, but neither of those are open source.

EDIT: Since nobody is responding, I'll give you what I think *should* be a pretty good method for repacking an app to an ipa. I just don't know how to differentiate between an app and its data

```
    mkdir /tempapp
    mkdir /tempapp/Payloads
    cp -R ~/Applications/$UUID/$NAME.app /tempapp/Payloads/
    cp ~/Applications/$UUID/iTunesArtwork /tempapp
    cp ~/Applications/$UUID/iTunesMetadata.plist /tempapp
    zip -r $NAME.ipa /tempapp/*
```

st

Comment: What do you mean by *"iTunes account of the user who bought it"*?  Are you simply referring to the iTunes *username* (email address) that's signed into on the device?  How are you planning to use this information?

Comment: I think all I need should be in iTunesMetadata.plist, but I'm not sure. The thing is if I don't include all the right metadata, the user won't be able to update their apps after using my program. It will say that the Apple ID is not present or request the Apple ID when opening the app. I don't want the user to have to enter their Apple ID when opening each app, that would take forever. Also, some other metadata is needed for the app itself to work properly.